# jQuery child embeded event listeners, parent removing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have:

**JavaScript:**

```
$('button#test').click(function(){
   //test
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="parent">
    <button id="test">click me</button>
</div>
```

then I do this:

```
$('div#parent').remove();
```

will the children binded event listeners be removed from the browser memory?

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are

[.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

> Similar to .empty(), the .remove() method takes elements out of the
>   DOM. Use .remove() when you want to remove the element itself, as well
>   as everything inside it. In addition to the elements themselves, all
>   bound events and jQuery data associated with the elements are removed.
>   To remove the elements without removing data and events, use .detach()
>   instead.

```js
var $child = $('#test').click(function() {});

var _data = $._data($child[0], 'events');
console.log(_data); //this will log the data object

var $parent = $('#parent').remove();

var _data = $._data($child[0], 'events');
console.log(_data); //this will log undefined
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <button id="test">click me</button>
</div>
```